# How to handle this delay on boot time?

Tags: boot, sysvinit, delay

friends! Happy New 2021 Year here!

I use Devuan with SysVinit, because I want to speedup my system and get unnecessary non-free stuff away as possible, but also I need Debian-like distribution cause of software and ease.

I want to discover why Atheros stops and also is it possible to initialize it after slim runs?

```
[    5.665127] ath9k_htc 1-1:1.0: ath9k_htc: FW Version: 1.4
[    5.665241] ath9k_htc 1-1:1.0: FW RMW support: On
[    5.665845] ath: EEPROM regdomain: 0x809c
[    5.665846] ath: EEPROM indicates we should expect a country code
[    5.665846] ath: doing EEPROM country->regdmn map search
[    5.665846] ath: country maps to regdmn code: 0x52
[    5.665847] ath: Country alpha2 being used: CN
[    5.665847] ath: Regpair used: 0x52
[    5.670273] ieee80211 phy1: Atheros AR9271 Rev:1
....here boot process stops for 3-4 seconds...
[   10.390281] usb 1-14: New USB device found, idVendor=0cf3, idProduct=e005, bcdDevice= 0.02
[   10.390707] usb 1-14: New USB device strings: Mfr=0, Product=0, SerialNumber=0
[   10.400582] ath9k_htc 1-1:1.0 wlx6cfdb9834ef2: renamed from wlan1
[   10.577632] Adding 1000444k swap on /dev/sdb3.  Priority:-2 extents:1 across:1000444k SSFS
[   10.604895] EXT4-fs (sdb2): re-mounted. Opts: (null)
[   10.810039] device-mapper: uevent: version 1.0.3
[   10.810588] device-mapper: ioctl: 4.39.0-ioctl (2018-04-03) initialised: dm-devel@redhat.com
[   10.866508] lp: driver loaded but no devices found
[   10.882348] ppdev: user-space parallel port driver
[   11.157659] EXT4-fs (sdc1): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: (null)
```

I have these services on my runlevel 2:

```
# ls /etc/rc2.d/
K01speech-dispatcher  S02acpi-fakekey   S02stop-bootlogd  S04acpid    S04dbus     S04mdadm  S04rmnologin  S05slim      S07rc.local
README            S02lvm2-lvmpolld  S02sudo       S04anacron  S04exim4    S04ntp    S04rsync      S05wicd
S01console-setup.sh   S02rsyslog    S02uuidd      S04cron     S04hddtemp  S04pcscd  S05elogind    S06bootlogs
```

PS: Why I moved from Debian with systemd to Devuan with sysvinit.
I had ugly delay on shutdown when used Debian with systemd - waiting some process kill. I know that it is possible to setup max delay for killing process. But another problem was ModemManager and wicd not connected after boot to wifi after some days of using and was some delay when opened wicd wifi connections window. So, I want better control and also i prefer opensource projects and computing freedom.

Comment: Have you installed `firmware-atheros`? It is non-free, but for some hardware to work you need those binary firmware blobs.

Comment: i have this package installed. you know my both wi-fi adapters (inner and external usb-adapter work without firmware on another FSF OS Guix). on Devuan there is /root/remove-firmware.sh but I still use firmware. Is it the reason?

Comment: You are using firmware in Guix too. Check the second paragraph of [Hardware Considerations (GNU Guix Reference Manual)](https://guix.gnu.org/manual/en/html_node/Hardware-Considerations.html)

Comment: yes, you are right. in Guix, I have firmware too like this ath9k-htc-firmware-1.4.0,  Line 'find /gnu/store -maxdepth 1 -type d -name *firmw* | wc -l' gives this - 6

Comment: Does `/var/log/messages` say anything around that time? (that's the place where you would see errors about firmware and other issues.